# Why am I getting a missing header error when calling the put file api for azure data lake gen2?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I am trying to call the gen2 rest endpoint directly and keep getting an error that I am missing a required header (MissingRequiredHeader message An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified. I fail to see what header is missing. I'm using the following code to send the request.

```
var client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://{account}.dfs.core.windows.net/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api_version", "2018-11-09");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authResult.AccessToken);

string azPath = $"{baseRawSystemPath}/{path.Replace("\\", "/")}";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
HttpContent body = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(azPath, body);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseListingJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return;
}
else
{
    var error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer my own question...  I was missing the resource=file query string parameter.  That allowed the request to succeed and the file to be created.